Create a decorative wall end cap
I have a brick wall that has been cut (ceiling to floor) which now needs to be finished off. I was thinking, 3 pieces of wood joined to slide over the wall end. Hopefully this would look like a wooden post at the end of the wall.
My question is, how would I cut and join the wood as I would like to keep it wood look (not painted)?
Or, does anyone have any other suggestions? The overall design of the area is industrial.

For this sort of "finish carpentry", you might get better answers in the Woodworking stack. My first instinct is miter joints, my second would be that if you want to really make it look like a single board you'd want to match grain patterns you would want something like a double book match but that's probably well beyond your skill range and available tools.

Constuct it like a door jamb. it won't look exactly like a post but it still won't look out of place - door jambs are an expected feature of walls.
Industrial you say,  folded sheet steel like used to make steel doorways is another option. or even a metal pipe or tube slit open to fit the wall.
The open side of a I beam or U channel could also work. (but the sheet steel may be less expensive, unless you get lucky at the junk yard).
